# How to resolve from an Injeactable its caller class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

Say I a class A which injects aclass B. In class B I need implicitly to get hold of the class which has inject class B. So in this case this would be class A.

Does anyone know how to receive this in a robust way?

Tried this as well but this gives me Logger not its caller.

```
Something like

@Stateless
@Dependent
public class Logger {

@Inject
InjectionPoint ip;

@Asynchronous
public void doSomething(){
   ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are talking about `@Dependent` scoped beans, there is [a way documented in the CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#injection_point).

The general idea is that CDI allows you to inject an object called `InjectionPoint` and from that you can get information on what bean injected this bean.

Here is a short snippet:

```
@Dependent //if you don't declare any scope, it's @Dependent by default
public class MyBean {
  @Inject
  InjectionPoint ip;

  public void doStuff() {
    // gives you the name of declaring class
    ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName(); 
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you might use a constructor injection in your bean to handle this during bean creation. It might be closer to what you aim for perhaps:

```
@Dependent //if you don't declare any scope, it's @Dependent by default
public class MyAnotherBean {
  public MyAnotherBean(InjectionPoint ip) {
    // CDI will inject InjectionPoint automatically
    ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName(); 
  }
}
```

Again, note that this **works for `@Dependent`** only! Why? Well, because `@Dependent` creates new instance per injection point and uses no proxy. Therefore you also know precisely who are you creating this instance for. Other scopes, such as `@RequestScoped`, `@SessionScoped` and so forth, do use a proxy and therefore you are only instantiating one object in CDI and then passing proxies whenever injection is requested.

Comment: Thanks , this seems to work.  This indeed looks like a more elegant solution! Thanks for your clear explanation as well!

Comment: @Bgvv1983 you are welcome. By the way, I see you marked your own answer as the solution. Does my answer miss anything? Just asking if I could/should provide any further info :)

Comment: Hmzz seems like its not working 
ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName(); 
 gives MyBean.class.

Comment: You haven't provided any code pieces so I cannot know what is `MyBean.class` and what are you expecting to get instead? Also, what are the scopes of your beans?

Comment: Hmm, I see. You in fact have EJB bean there and not just CDI. I am not sure works together. I will double check this and get to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135078/discussion-between-siliarus-and-bgvv1983).

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I found a solution.

Made a HelperClass. which containst an @AroundInvoke method.

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object injectMap(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
    StackTraceElement element = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[CLASS_NAME_ELEMENT];
    return ic.proceed();
}
```

In Class A I annotate the method which needs Uses the injectable class B with:

```
@Interceptors(ContextHelper.class)
```

This seems to work for what I want.

Comment: While this might work, it seems pretty hardcore. Anyhow, I would advise to use CDI interceptors (e.g. annotation `@Interceptor` and `@InterceptorBinding`) rather than EJB ones as you have here. While this might work, EJB interceptors are not exactly first class citizens in CDI.